# How to specific background normal color for android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle button

Tags: android

I was wondering, how can I specific background normal color a `?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle` button?

Currently, I have the following button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buy_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="?attr/shopButtonTextColor"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"        
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/shop_buy" />
```

It looks like

### Normal

[image]

### Pressed (Has ripple effect)

[image]

What I'm expecting is

- During normal, it has orange background.
- During pressed, it has `colorControlHighlight` (Usually grey) color ripple overlay on the top of orange background.

I do the following modification.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buy_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="?attr/shopButtonTextColor"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:background="@color/shop_button_background_color_material_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/shop_buy" />
```

[image]

The padding/ margin information seem gone.

When I press on it, the previous ripple selector is gone.

I was wondering, how can I use `?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle`, yet able to achieve the following?

- Retain padding/ margin in `?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle`.
- Retain round corner (I guess is 2dp) behavior of the `?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle` button.
- During normal, it has orange background.
- During pressed, it has `colorControlHighlight` (Usually grey) color ripple overlay on the top of orange background.

Comment: From your description, you need `?attr/buttonStyle` instead of `?attr/borderlessButtonStyle`.

Comment: And to get the orange background, override `colorButtonNormal` under your app's theme and set it to the color you want.

Comment: And you should set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` in your `Button's` xml definition.

Comment: Hi Vikram, your proposed solution works pretty well for me - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/60bda9461c1a6551410e9eaeb6c24379#file-flat-button My only concern is, is it too "heavy", to have my custom button theme `Shop.Button.Light` inherits from my entire app theme? Is that a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Vikram. I was able to achieve a nice flat button effect, with desired background color by using the following technique.

```
<style name="ShopButton">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/shop_button_background_color_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/shop_button_background_color_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/shop_button_text_color_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buy_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?attr/buttonStyle"
    android:theme="@style/ShopButton"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:text="@string/shop_buy" />
```

It looks as the following

[image]

Comment: Let's discuss this here: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111269/how-to-make-styleattr-actionbuttonstyle-workable-for-rectangle-toolbar-button).